# How hex from binary file converts to decimal

Tags: conversion, hexadecimal, hex-editor

I know how to convert HEX<->Decimal up to `255` will be `0xFF` = `255`

however HEX for `1040` is `0x410` i am not getting how to do this working
please explain with graphics representation i am visual person not good with words and mathematics.

This example from online trying to explain it,
1457 / 16 = 91.0625
91 / 16 = 5.6875
5 / 16 = 0

I almost understand this, but where they a re getting remainder 11 in 91 / 16 = 5.6875?

**Edit:** got it remainder is 5 * 16 = 80 then 91 - 80 = 11, doh they should have mentioned that however not single site i go to mentions this.

How do you put it back to decimal though?
[image]

**Main question** inside binary file i get 2 bytes HEX that reads `10 04` and this somehow also converts to `1040` decimal (int8 or int32) how that works?

Comment: `dec_value=5*16*16 +11*16 +1` as 'B' is '11' in decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Main question** inside binary file i get 2 bytes HEX that reads 10 04 and this somehow also converts to 1040 decimal (int8 or int32) how that works?

It's the same 0x410 but in [little-endian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) byte order, i.e. backwards.

Usually the specification of the file format will mention whether its integer fields are stored in big-endian or little-endian. (Or sometimes a mix of both...) If it's not specified, then LE is probably the more likely option if the file format comes from PC, as that's how x86 CPUs (i.e. typical PCs) store multi-byte values in memory.